# Dedicated Control / Deck to switch between tjhe input sources of my monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I'm using a Dell UP2716D Monitor and a Dell S3422DWG monitor on my desk. I use these monitors with several computers via their various input sources and this basically works fine.

But I'm sick and tired of using the physical buttons to switch between my computers. I always have to get up, the buttons are not easily accessible (the S3422DWG hides them on the back) and everytime I touch the buttons I change the alignment of the monitors which results in them moving over time.

Can I change the input source some other way? Is there maybe a remote control? Or some sort of button-deck I can plug into each monitor via USB? Or a shortcut from the command line? But the shortcut must work from Ubuntu and windows 10. I'd prefer something like a Stream Deck.

Anyone got an idea? Thanks and best regards.